# Access User group instance from FilterSet init Django

Tags: django, filter

I am trying to set django filter choices for User Groups.

I have tried setting the **init** function but I am not able to get the self.request to access user's groups.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Filter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.filters['group'].extra['choices'] = [
           (group.id, group.name) for group in self.request.user.groups.all()
       ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to access the User or Group instance using the request as the request is always of the None type. So I used django_currentuser library and got it working

Here is the code:

```
from django_currentuser.middleware import get_current_user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    user = get_current_user()
    
    self.filters['group'].extra['choices'] = [
        (group.id, group.name) for group in user.groups.all()
    ]
```